# React inlines style not working with some attributes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I supposed that react parameter gridRowStart will be translated to grid-row-start, same as zIndex is translated to z-index.
But it does not work, do you have any idea why?

My render method:

```
render() {
var divStyle = {
      background: '#92f442',
      gridRowStart: 1,
      zIndex: 2
};
return (
      <div style={divStyle}>
      </div>
)};
```

unfortunately in chrome i the element has only 2 attributes

```
<div style="background: rgb(146, 244, 66); z-index: 2;"></div>
```

What's more, I've tried to use attibutes from React doc
https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/style-props-value-px.html
unfortunately not all attributes are visible:

RENDERED ATTRIBUTES:

- columnCount,fillOpacity, flex, stopOpacity, strokeDashoffset, strokeOpacity, strokeWidth, tabSize, widows, zIndex, zoom, lineHeight, opacity, columnCount, fillOpacity, flex, animationIterationCount

NOT RENDERED:

- columnCount, boxFlex, boxFlexGroup, boxOrdinalGroup, flexGrow, flexPositive, flexShrink, flexNegative, flexOrder, fontWeight, lineClamp, order, orphans

Other attributes like 'example' or 'whatever' attribute are omitted as well.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: i'm using Google chrome

Comment: Having issue with lineClamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are probably using these CSS props in a way that your browser ignores them. Check out this simple example:

```
<div style={{ display: 'grid', height: 200, gridTemplate: '200px / repeat(4, 1fr)' }}>
  <div style={{ background: 'lime', gridRowStart: 'span 2', zIndex: 2   }}>Hello {this.props.name}</div>
  <div style={{ background: 'yellow' }}></div>
  <div style={{ background: 'blue' }}></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LsL6yn7k/

It has a valid gridRowStart set and if you inspect the rendered element you will see that grid-row-start style is set as expected.

Comment: This is the right answer, having re-read the `grid-row-start` spec. I was fooled by Chrome accepting `1` as a valid value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you saved a lot of my time :)

Answer (score 0):

React [converts most unitless numeric CSS values into pixels](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/c78464f8ea9a5b00ec80252d20a71a1482210e57/src/renderers/dom/shared/dangerousStyleValue.js#L44). So, for example, `{ paddingLeft: 10 }` becomes `{ paddingLeft: '10px' }`.

It has a  [list of CSS properties which accept numbers but are not in units of "px".](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/c78464f8ea9a5b00ec80252d20a71a1482210e57/src/renderers/dom/shared/CSSProperty.js#L14). Properties on this list are treated as plain numbers.

`gridRowStart` isn't on this list, so React transforms the value into `{ gridRowStart: 1px }`. That isn't a [valid value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row-start#Values), so the div's `style` property is not updated.

`gridRow` is on the `unitless` list, so the style is updated correctly:

```
const Test = () => {
  var divStyle = {
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    gridRow: 1
  };

  return <div style={divStyle}>React</div>;
}

// renders:
// <div style="background-color: yellow; grid-row: 1 auto;">React</div>
```

**Note:** you'll need to enable "Experimental Web Platform Technologies" in Chrome's `about://flags` to use grid layout.

https://jsfiddle.net/wysj7jx1/5/